# Обновление данных формы angularJS после окончания ввода

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="contact.email" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
<div class="alert alert-danger input-error" ng-show="ContactForm.email.$dirty && ContactForm.email.$invalid">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    Введите корректный Email
</div>
```

Есть вот такой код. Сейчас работает так: обновляю страницу - все норм, кликаю по полю, ввожу что-то - выскакивает ошибка `alert-danger`. Как сделать, чтобы она выскакивала только после окончания ввода? `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` не помогло.

Comment: Я думаю, нужно немного глубже смотреть, на ввод поля стоит onchage?

Answer (score 1):

А попробуйте так

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="contact.email" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
<div class="alert alert-danger input-error" ng-show="ContactForm.email.$touched && ContactForm.email.$invalid">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    Введите корректный Email
</div>
```

Свойство `$touched` будет `true`, когда фокус ввода покинул поле. Нужен Angular 1.3+